# Will 360 games such as Guitar Hero recognize my USB midi device if I plug it directly into a controller port?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

does anyone know if I can connect a usb MIDI device (my drum machine) directly to a controller port and have it recognised within the likes of Guitar Hero?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A Generic USB MIDI device? No.

Xbox 360 games (like Guitar Hero and Rockband) actually receive input from their controllers are if they were standard controllers with a few modifications.  By comparison a Drum Machine which outputs MIDI does not conform to the standards.  More than likely the Xbox will not know how to handle the input and ignore it.

Comment: "By comparison a Drum Machine which outputs MIDI does not conform to the standards". Not even if I tweak the MIDI device's output configuration so that it sends the note numbers the xbox is expecting?

Comment: @Jim the interface between the Xbox and its controller is not so simple that you can just hack together a simple adjustment.  What's worse, the Xbox doesn't take "notes" as input, but rather a more basic input which is time sensitive for specific notes.  You'd have to handle the registration of the controller, then know the timings of the notes in the game and sync the two up.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't plug it directly in but if you buy the MIDI adapter for rock band:[image]

you can use your drums with Rock Band 3. Quick links for the easy [shopping,](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=pro+midi+adapter+rockband&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=ivnsfd&resnum=3&biw=1967&bih=925&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=1200976101452524836&ei=4ZEhTbeYFMO78gbl6sSbDg&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CFgQ8wIwAw#)

Comment: Thanks, but thats the bit I'm trying to avoid. Cheers.

Comment: Does your MIDI instrument already have buttons for 'Start' and 'Back' and up/down/left/right?

Comment: there is no avoiding it, sadly. The only way you could use it directly is if you are good enough to mod your box and write the drivers for yourself, which if you can, you should so we can all have them :)